# Adobe Interview: What data structure to use for storing thousands of points (x,y) to perform certain operations faster

Tags: data-structures

We have to store thousands of points (x,y,c) c here is for color of that point. Mainly its related to pixels on the screen. We have to perform operations :
given x = i, we have to change color of all the points having x = i.
Similary, given y = i, we have to change color of all the points having y = i.

I proposed a solution of 2D-matrix. Then Separate Hash table for x and y coordinates.
Then he asked me for even better solution.
What better combinations of data structures can we use ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need both a 2D array and separate hashtables. If your data is dense, representing all (or most) of a rectangular region, then a 2D array by itself is sufficient. You could ask as a followup which coordinate is most likely to be used for lookup, and then structure the arrays do that the outer coordinate is that one so that lookup in that coordinate is localized in memory but otherwise you can't do much better. Conversely, for sparse data the hashtables are the best you can do. (I'm assuming you are hashing the coordinate to an array of point objects.) Was there perhaps more information given about the nature of the data or how it is most likely to be used?

Comment: When i said i will use hash table for a x coordinate, as for corresponding y coordinates collisions will occur, for those i will use linked lists, so Then Interviewer said that if i am already using pionters in these linked lists can i do better making use of these pointers.

Comment: I dont know, Maybe he was suggesting to somehow combine x and y hash tables together to save space.

Answer (score 1):

If no retrieval wrt one coordinate: you may propose hashing x,y pairs of coordinates. Post propose some hash with low collosion, as does `hash = ( y << 16 ) ^ x;`.

But you wish to access your data wrt value for x or y. The structure to store points and efficiently perform operations on it is a point QTree or Quad Tree. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

> The point quadtree is an adaptation of a binary tree used to represent
>   two dimensional point data. It shares the features of all quadtrees
>   but is a true tree as the center of a subdivision is always on a
>   point.
>
> A node of a point quadtree is similar to a node of a binary tree, with
>   the major difference being that it has four pointers (one for each
>   quadrant) instead of two ("left" and "right") as in an ordinary binary
>   tree. Also a key is usually decomposed into two parts, referring to x
>   and y coordinates. Therefore a node contains following information: 4
>   Pointers: quad[‘NW’], quad[‘NE’], quad[‘SW’], and quad[‘SE’] point;
>   which in turn contains: key; usually expressed as x, y coordinates
>   value; for example a name

Then, you can have a recursive function for querying all points within a AABB range. You can adapt this implementation of `QueryRange()`

```
class QuadTree
{
  function queryRange(AABB range)
  {
    Array of XY pointsInRange;  // Prepare an array of results

    // Check objects at this quad level
    for (int p := 0; p < points.size; p++)
    {
      if (range.containsPoint(points[p]))
        pointsInRange.append(points[p]);
    }

    pointsInRange.appendArray(northWest->queryRange(range));
    pointsInRange.appendArray(northEast->queryRange(range));
    pointsInRange.appendArray(southWest->queryRange(range));
    pointsInRange.appendArray(southEast->queryRange(range));

    return pointsInRange;
  }
}
```

Comment: A quad tree is space efficient and query efficient for rectangular regions but not efficient at all for operations on an entire index like the one described here.

Comment: why not efficient for ranges limited to one element

Comment: Its O(log(n)) lookup worst case and if you are expanding an entire index that way you will hit the worst case performance. Conversely, both the hashtable and matrix approaches are O(1) lookup.

Comment: maybe query range algo is costly, but structure is nevertheless suited for points storage retrieval

Comment: Suited in what way? There are no data structures that are "suited" for a particular type of data unless you specify the expected access patterns. For example if the data is dense and the access pattern is entire rows and columns with uniform likelihood in every index then a quad tree is strictly worse than a 2d array - slower to access and requiring more storage space.